# req.param gives undefined on server side : nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am using nodejs and angularjs.

1. I sent get request to nodejs server with required data in parameters in my client side js.

   itinerary.js

   ```
   $http({
       method : "GET",
       url : '/createItinerary',
       data : {
           "source" : $scope.sourceDestination.source,
           "destination" : $scope.sourceDestination.destination
       }
   })
   ```
2. I the node js file, when I am using req.params("source") or req.params("destination"), I am getting undefined in them.

   createIitinerary.js

   ```
   exports.check = function(req,res){
   // These two variables come from the form on
   var source = req.param("source");
   var dest = req.param("destination");

   console.log("source:"+source);
   console.log("dest:"+dest);

   var json_responses;

   if(source == dest){
       json_responses = {"statusCode" : 401};
       res.send(json_responses)
   }
   else{
       json_responses = {"statusCode" : 200};
       res.send(json_responses);
   }};
   ```

Question: When I use Post, the data is correctly received in nodejs, but not with Get. Why is this? How can I send data to nodejs using Get request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `$http.get()` you set `params` not `data`

Try:

```
 $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : '/createItinerary',
        params: {
            "source" : $scope.sourceDestination.source,
            "destination" : $scope.sourceDestination.destination
        }
    })
```

it should be easy to inspect the url used in browser dev tools network and make sure it looks right

Answer (score 0):

If you read about http verbs then you will come to know that if the method is of type **GET** then we can't send data in the body.

We can send the data as query parameters if the request is of type GET
so your request will become

```
       $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : '/createItinerary?source=$scope.sourceDestination.source&destination=$scope.sourceDestination.destination
        })
```

And you can read data on server side as

```
req.query.source
req.query.destination
```

You can send the data in body if the method type is **PUT**,**POST**, **DELETE**, **UPDATE** etc.

Conclusion

**NEVER PUT BODY IN GET REQUEST**

Comment: you need to concatenate those variables into the url string...can't just include them as part of the string. Much easier and less error prone to let angular parse the `params` object